# Matching Pantone color chips to Munsell color chips

Tags: color, pantone

I am rewriting an ASTM standard and am looking to identify a Pantone color chip that matches as closely as possible a specific Munsell color chip referenced in the current standard. Is there a way to match colors in the two systems?

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few colour converters online if you do a Google Search *(e.g. 'convert pantone to munsell')*. I'm assuming you're ok to compare using reference codes rather than needing the tangible cards in front of you? Here's one of the results from Googling:

http://www.colormunki.com/munsell

You can select a colour in the Pantone or Munsell library and then ask it to show you the same colour in the other library.

Comment: I think the biggest problem is that a panatone color is aboit the ink while munsel is about the color. So you will have some variation based on medium.

Comment: @joojaa I think that, objectively, you can find a pantone ref that is more similar to a munsell ref, objectively, than the other pantone refs, and I think this conversion is relevant to the question asked (*'as closely as possibly*), albeit using Pantone's Goa Coated system. But it is a clarification worth knowing, yes.